# Recovering commits lost after "hg strip"

Tags: mercurial

I have this Mercurial repository where I keep a counter:

```
$ echo 1 > count
$ hg add count 
$ hg com -m 'incrementing to 1'
$ echo 2 > count
$ hg com -m 'incrementing to 2'
```

So far so good, but then I committed a mistake:

```
$ hg com -m 'incrementing to 3'
```

So I use `hg strip` to revert this last commit:

```
$ hg strip --keep -r -2
saved backup bundle to /home/adam/sandbox/count/.hg/strip-backup/bda856a578bf-ff2b025f-backup.hg
```

Unbeknownst to me, I have committed another, bigger mistake! I stripped the two topmost commits, and I just wanted to strip the topmost one:

```
$ hg log
changeset:   0:7b5533cf962a
tag:         tip
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed May 15 08:00:27 2019 -0300
summary:     incrementing to 1
```

How I get my commits back?

*NOTE*: this is a contrived example of a case were I needed to use `hg strip`. No need to wasting time pointing out there are alternatives etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've learned from [this message in Mercurial's mailing list](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2011-July/039016.html), the solution is quite straightforward. Note that when I ran `hg strip --keep -r -2` I got this line in the output:

```
saved backup bundle to /home/adam/sandbox/count/.hg/strip-backup/bda856a578bf-ff2b025f-backup.hg
```

So, basically, Mercurial made a backup of the original history! Now I just need to pull from it:

```
$ hg pull /home/adam/sandbox/count/.hg/strip-backup/bda856a578bf-ff2b025f-backup.hg
pulling from /home/adam/sandbox/count/.hg/strip-backup/bda856a578bf-ff2b025f-backup.hg
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 2 changesets with 2 changes to 1 files
(run 'hg update' to get a working copy)
$ hg update
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

My file is back to the original state...

```
$ cat count 
66
```

...as well as my history:

```
$ hg log
changeset:   2:fc4d1cc18a4b
tag:         tip
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed May 15 08:00:51 2019 -0300
summary:     incrementing to 3

changeset:   1:bda856a578bf
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed May 15 08:00:38 2019 -0300
summary:     incrementing to 2

changeset:   0:7b5533cf962a
user:        Adam Victor Nazareth Brandizzi <brandizzi@gmail.com>
date:        Wed May 15 08:00:27 2019 -0300
summary:     incrementing to 1
```

Now I can call the right strip command (`hg strip --keep -r -1`).

## What if we do not have the backup file name anymore?

You may have lost the backup file name (it did happen to me!) but you can find it in `$YOUR_REPO/.hg/strip-backup`. If you have many backups, just list them sorted by time, descending:

```
$ ls -tl .hg/strip-backup/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adam adam 754 May 15 08:10 bda856a578bf-ff2b025f-backup.hg    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adam adam 754 May 15 08:02 02ac79859dd0-0902f53b-backup.hg
```

The last one is probably the one you want.